# Gazettes with Stanford NER

Tags: stanford-nlp, crf, crf++

I am making my own model of Stanford NER which is CRF based, by following conventions given at this [link](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml).
I want to add Gazettes and following [this](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#gazette) from same link. I am mentioning all of my Gazettes using this property, **gazette=file1.txt;file2.txt** and also mentioning **useGazettes=true** in **austen.prop**. 
After making model when I am testing data from my Gazettes then **it is not TAGGING correctly**. The tag which I mentioned in files in not coming correctly. These are little bit surprising results for me as Stanford NER is not giving them same tag as mentioned in those files.

Is there some limitations of Stanford NER with Gazettes or I am still missing something? If somebody can help me I will be thankful to you.

Comment: Hey, did you solve this problem?

Comment: I was trying all of these things in Stanford version 3.5.2. With that version I was unable to solve it. But now they have version 3.6.0 and I did not try with this version. So, I can not say anything about this latest version.

Comment: I have the same problem with 3.6.0, look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932299/entities-on-my-gazette-are-not-recognized

Comment: Yes, same problem and it is very painful when we don't get response. Good luck for you.