# Entities on my gazette are not recognized

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I would like to create a custom NER model. That's what i did:

**TRAINING DATA** (stanford-ner.tsv):

```
Hello    O
!    O
My    O
name    O
is    O
Damiano    PERSON
.    O
```

**PROPERTIES** (stanford-ner.prop):

```
trainFile = stanford-ner.tsv
serializeTo = ner-model.ser.gz
map = word=0,answer=1
maxLeft=1
useClassFeature=true
useWord=true
useNGrams=true
noMidNGrams=true
maxNGramLeng=6
usePrev=true
useNext=true
useDisjunctive=true
useSequences=true
usePrevSequences=true
useTypeSeqs=true
useTypeSeqs2=true
useTypeySequences=true
wordShape=chris2useLC
useGazettes=true
gazette=gazzetta.txt
cleanGazette=true
```

**GAZZETTE** gazzetta.txt):

```
PERSON John
PERSON Andrea
```

I build the model via command line with:

```
java -classpath "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier  -prop stanford-ner.prop
```

And test with:

```
java -classpath "stanford-ner.jar:lib/*" edu.stanford.nlp.ie.crf.CRFClassifier  -loadClassifier ner-model.ser.gz -textFile test.txt
```

I did two tests with the following texts:

**>>> TEST 1 <<<**

- TEXT:
  Hello! My name is Damiano and this is a fake text to test.
- OUTPUT
  *Hello/O !/O
  My/O name/O is/O Damiano/PERSON and/O this/O is/O a/O fake/O text/O to/O test/O ./O*

**>>> TEST 2 <<<**

- TEXT:
  Hello! My name is John and this is a fake text to test.
- OUTPUT
  *Hello/O !/O
  My/O name/O is/O John/O and/O this/O is/O a/O fake/O text/O to/O test/O ./O*

As you can see only "Damiano" entity is found. This entity is in my training data but "John" (second test) is inside the gazzette. So the question is.

Why does John entity is not recognized ?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Stanford FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#gazette) says,

> If a gazette is used, this does not guarantee that words in the
>   gazette are always used as a member of the intended class, and it does
>   not guarantee that words outside the gazette will not be chosen. It
>   simply provides another feature for the CRF to train against. If the
>   CRF has higher weights for other features, the gazette features may be
>   overwhelmed.
>
> If you want something that will recognize text as a member of a class
>   if and only if it is in a list of words, you might prefer either the
>   regexner or the tokensregex tools included in Stanford CoreNLP. The
>   CRF NER is not guaranteed to accept all words in the gazette as part
>   of the expected class, and it may also accept words outside the
>   gazette as part of the class.

Btw, it is not a good practice to test machine learning pipelines in a 'unit-test'-way, i.e. with only one or two examples, because it is supposed to work on much greater volume of data and, more importantly, it is probabilistic by nature.

If you want to check if your gazette file is actually used, it may be better to take existent examples (see the bottom of the page linked above for `austen.gaz.prop` and `austen.gaz.txt` examples) and replace multiple names by your own ones, then check. If it fails, firstly try to change your test, e.g. add more names, reformulate text and so on.

Comment: Yes i read it, but if it found "Damiano" as entity i do not understand why it does not recognize another name (inside the gazette). It seems that the model only looks at the names i used inside the training data. However i am creating this model because i need to find entities inside resume/cv. Do you think is better to use all the resume/cv text for each entity i need to find? for example... i need the person name, inside a resume there are many. I need the personal name (that often is on the first 10 lines ), is better to add all the text to let the model understand the position too?

Comment: 1) The fact that Stanford NER didn't find 'John' doesn't mean that Stanford NER ignores gazette. 2) But yes, it is better to make train data as similar to real (test) data and as big as possible. So, I'd propose to create much bigger train set (say, dozens of examples) and use big gazette (e.g with all person names) at the same time.

Comment: So for example, if i have the personal name at the first line of the resume do you think is better to add all the other sentences of the resume too, right?

Comment: It is unlikely to hurt, but I don't think it is the best way to trade your time for quality. First of all, I'd start with prepared NER model instead of training my own and look at results. If existed model works bad, then I'd create train set from 50-100 CVs (if the name always occurs in the 1st sentence, then I'd take only first sentences). After that I'd implement cross-validation and if results are still bad, inspect errors manually.

Comment: How can the model understands what are the best sentences that have the entities if i do not specify the "negative" sentences? because there are many names so i need to train it to avoid false positives. no? Do i not need them ? after this i will accept yours answer! thank you sooo much!

Comment: If your task is to find author's name given CV, then I suggest to simply apply NER with prepared model, then take the first occurrence of class PERSON - it will be required name. Most probably, it will be enough. If that strategy fails, then search for the reason (I see 2 possible ones): (1) if names are not found by NER in your data, then - and only then - try to use custom NER model; (2) if NER works correctly, but the first occurrence of PERSON isn't the one you are searching, then try other heuristics (ask yourself, how would you search it) and, maybe, train separated classifier.

Comment: ...and if proposed simple strategy fails and you can't fix it, then create new question and describe your actual task in more details.

Answer (score 1):

gazzette will only help for extracting extra features from the training data, if you don't have any occurrence of these words inside your training data or any connection to labeled tokens, your model will not benefits from that. One of the experiments that I would suggest is to add `Damiano` to your gazzette.

Comment: If i have "Damiano" inside the training data, what is the purpose of adding the same in the gazzette ?

Comment: It helps with detecting `John` and `Andrea` in the similar context to `Damiano`.

Comment: ok but if i repeat "Damiano" inside the training data AND the gazzette i should do the same for all the names. If not, why ? Thanks for the clarification

Comment: Let me give another example, Suppose you have a big list of country names inside the gazzette but you only have few of them inside your training data. Since for those ones inside the training data you have Location as label and it has a gazzette feature (exists inside the gazzette as a Location), this can potentially help the model to generalize and detect other country names which are missing inside the training data.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does John entity is not recognized ?

It looks to me that your minimal example should most probably add "Damiano" to the gazetteer as a PERSON category. Currently, the training data allows the model to learn that "Damiano" is a PERSON label, but I think this is not related to the gazetteer categories (i.e. having PERSON on both sides is not sufficient).

Comment: I have labeled Damiano as PERSON (in model) and labeled Johh as PERSON in gazetteer. Do i need the same persons list in model and gazetteer ?

Comment: You should have gazetteer and training data (what do you mean by model?). Gazetteer should contain lists of relevant lexical units (names), as exhaustive as possible, while training data gives examples of sentences containing those lexical units. Both are important and contain as much data as possible.