# unable to tag gazette entities using own crf model

Tags: crf, named-entity-recognition

I followed this [Entities on my gazette are not recognized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38932299/entities-on-my-gazette-are-not-recognized)
Even after adding minimal example of training data "Damiano" in gazette entity i am not able to recognition John or Andrea as PERSON.

I tried this using on large training data and gazette but still not able to tag any gazette entity. why?